# Insert into MySQL with foreign key and automatically create new foreign key if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables with a foreign key relationship. Let's call them *args* and *arglist*.

```sql
create table args (id int not null,
  arg varchar not null,
  primary key (id),
  unique index (arg)
);

create table arglist (id int not null,
   arg1 int not null,
   arg2 int not null,
   foreign key arg1 references args(id),
   foreign key arg2 references args(id),
   primary key (id),
   index (arg1),
   index (arg2)
);
```

The not-so-elegant way to insert arbitrary args into arglist is to do an `insert ignore` and then to do a `select` to get the id for each arg and then to insert into arglist.

Sort of like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO args (arg) VALUES ('newarg1'),('newarg2');
INSERT INTO arglist (arg1,arg2) VALUES ((SELECT id from args where arg='newarg1'),(SELECT id from args where arg='newarg2'));
```

That's 2 round-trips to the database server. Is there a way to do this with a single insert?

Comment: Could do with a bit more detail.

Comment: *"That's 5 round-trips to the database server. Is there a way to do this with a single insert?"*  Premature optimisation?  Do you have performance issues now or do you think you will get them? Assuming args does not change alot you could cache it..  But this method sounds more that you should be worring more about hard to debug race conditions as the way how you descriped it feels prone and might cause (unexpected) errors on the application side..

Comment: Args never changes; it's a write-once table. And yes, my initial computations is that I'm going to be updating arglist (well, the real table, whose name I can't put here) roughly 6000 times every 1-5 minutes. So I'd like to keep the round-trips under control.

Comment: *"That's 3 round-trips to the database server. Is there a way to do this with a single insert?"*  No the best is two ... `INSERT IGNORE INTO args (arg) VALUES ('newarg1'), ('newarg2'); INSERT INTO arglist (arg1,arg2) VALUES ((SELECT id from args where arg='newarg1'),(SELECT id from args where arg='newarg2'));`  as you are dealing with two separated tables also you might want to do this with in `BEGIN;  COMMIT;` to make it a transaction instead..   ..

Comment: .. only problem not sure what `INSERT IGNORE` does with a transaction state as `INSERT IGNORE` is really iffy to use like you already said.. what you can try is MySQL's *"upsert"* instead -> `INSERT INTO args (arg) ('newarg1'), ('newarg2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE arg = VALUES(arg)` instead to avoid `INSERT IGNORE`..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, thanks. I'll shorten mine to two. Be nice to get it to one.

Comment: *"I'll shorten mine to two. Be nice to get it to one."*  Like is said before that is simpley not really  possible as you need to insert into **two** separted tables .. A method could be using a stored procedure to make only one round trip but that also is not going to make this more easy or better performing..

Comment: Okay. If you wish to add this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: You might want to fix the create and insert statements before proceeding..

Comment: if you really really want to save roundtrips consider using [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html) instead as RDMS..   it is possible to do  `INSERT .... RETURNING id` there is also a *"upsert"* part with `ON CONFLICT` but not sure if you can combine it with `RETURNING id` (as i never done that, the manual's BNF suggests it should be possible) ... if that is safely possible it should be possible there to use one (big) statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus of the discussion in the comments is that there is no way to shorten this with MySQL, and as a result of the comments, the original set of 5-statements was shortened to 2. Thanks to everyone who commented.